# Why can't I require modules in Node.js shell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

**In English**

I'm getting some unexpected results when I try to load a module using `require` in the Node.js shell to play around with it (as opposed to writing a script and running that with Node). In a script, for example, I can do:

```
var _ = require('grunt');
grunt.registerTask(/* ...*/);
```

And this works fine. But when I try to do this in the Node.js shell, it first can't find the module unless I specify the `node_modules` directory, and then calling one of the modules' methods only works once before it stops.

**In Tech-Speake**

In current directory, I have the following subdirectory:

```
- node_modules
  - lodash
  - grunt
```

Now I want to play around with the Node.js shell, using one of the installed libraries:

```
$ node
> var _ = require('lodash');
undefined

> _ = require('./node_modules/lodash');
// Long output of function list
```

Now if I try to use lodash, it works once and then stops and I have to import it again:

```
_.reduce(/* ... */); //Works
_.reduce(/* ... */); // TypeError: Cannot call method 'reduce' of undefined
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`_` as the var name does not work as Node uses it to hold the result of the last operation. Try something like:

```
> var l = require('lodash'); 
> l.reduce(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realized that! I wonder why I am able to call it `_` in a written script, then.

Comment: @A.Duff `_` only contains the result of the previous operation in the REPL.  It wouldn't make much sense in a script; if you need access to the result, you'd assign it to something.